# How to delete data from database after select query excuted successfully

Tags: mysql, mysqladministrator

My Question is that when data is select successfully then delete from MySQL db.When Select  Query is fails due to  large  data then it can not delete data using shell script because  in that case select data are also with image store in system then it can also move to another location and make it to tar file.

Comment: Can you please clarify you question and include details such as the query you are using and how much data is involved? Thanks.

Comment: MySQL Query Is that like

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`savan`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_anpr_1`()
BEGIN
 if exists (SELECT * FROM anpr where datetime < DATE((now() - interval 6 month)) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/anpr_DATE.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  )
    then
 delete from anpr where datetime < DATE((now() - interval 6 month));
  elseif not exists(select * from anpr where datetime < DATE((now() - interval 6 month)))
   then 
    select 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE';
  else
   select 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE';
 end if;
END

Comment: when outfile use getting syntax error i could not fond that error.

Comment: My Question is that data is exported in csv file  using select query run successfully without any error then delete from database. @AbySheffer